# Poor usage of timestamp index

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, mysql-5.7, ndbcluster

with a small table (about 2 M of rows, 5 classic columns, id, description, title, created_at, coordinates (point)) doing a WHERE created_at BETWEEN ... AND ... ORDER BY created_at LIMIT 50 is very very slow (about 15 seconds)

`created_at` is `timestamp` with index.

But when I use EXPLAIN, the column filtered shows 10, which is bad.
What could be the cause of this 10 ?

Query is simple, table is innodb, no partition

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2016-10-28 18:25:00' 
                     AND '2016-11-02 18:25:00' 
ORDER BY created_at DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

Explain plan

```
1   SIMPLE  posts   NULL    range   created_at  created_at  5   NULL    5317    10.00   Using index condition; Using where
```

Mysql 5.7 clustered version

(Added from comments)

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    title varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '', 
    description text NOT NULL, 
    created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    status tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
    context tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    coordinates point DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    KEY created_at (created_at), 
    KEY status (status), 
    KEY context (context)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `EXPLAIN` is about as good as it will get.  "Range" is good for the `WHERE`.  The `ORDER BY`, though not mentioned, should be handled as well.  And it should stop at 50 (again, no clue in `EXPLAIN`).

`10.00` percent of the table is an estimate based on virtually no information; ignore it.

"5.7 clustered" is a contradiction.  Do you mean "NDB Cluster"?  Or a Galera-based cluster?

Indexing a flag `(status)` is usually useless.

More on [*indexing*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/compound-composite-indexes/) .

Back to the question of 15 seconds.  I agree that the time is unreasonably large.  Here are some partial explanations...

- Something else was busy in the system.
- The bulky `TEXT` column was store off-record, necessitating an extra disk hit.  Granted, 50 disk hits should take less than a second.
- The Posts may be scattered around; that is, not stored consecutively.  Again, maybe 50 disk hits and another fraction of a second.

I am surprised that it took more than one second, even after allowing for uncached blocks.

Run the query a second time (to counteract the caching); how long does it take?

Another thing to check -- how big is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and how big is RAM?  A tiny VM could be *part* of the problem.  The buffer_pool being so big that swapping occurs could actually explain 15 seconds.

Comment: Yes it's 5.7 NDB Cluster, sorry. For theflag index, yes we are making some other tests with composite. Tunning the query a second time take 308 ms. I'm not sure to well understand "the posts may be scattered", but after controls, it seems that the table (a test table) was populated by a script with a random created_at date at each row. So we have unordered created date in column from 2012 to 2016. It could explain what the "scattered" notion, isnt'it ? Buffer pool size is 134217728
and RAM is 16 Go (just a test server).

Comment: After tests and re-populate table as it would be in the real life (ordered by created_at ASC), add an auto-increment 'ID' in more 'POST_ID' that is not sequential, it seems to be better. About 3 sec the first attempt. Still too much but @Rick, thanks for the "scattered" idea.

Comment: There are _so many_ differences between NDB and non-NDB, that I don't trust anything I have said.  I tagged it 'ndbcluster'; maybe an expert from there can help you.  But wait...  You say `ENGINE=InnoDB`; how can it be NDB?